# Substitute a regex pattern using awk

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I am trying to write a regex expression to replace one or more '+' symbols present in a file with a space. I tried the following:

```
 echo This++++this+++is+not++done | awk '{ sub(/\++/, " "); print }'
 This this+++is+not++done
```

Expected:

```
This this is not done
```

Any ideas why this did not work?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `gsub` which does global substitution:

```
echo This++++this+++is+not++done | awk '{gsub(/\++/," ");}1'
```

`sub` function replaces only 1st match, to replace all matches use `gsub`.

Comment: what is the `1` at the end for?

Comment: @DrunkenPoney The `1` at the end tells AWK to print out the line after it's been `gsub`ed on. You can avoid it by explicitly adding a print statement to the same action as the `gsub`, e.g. ```{gsub(/\++/," "); print;}```

Comment: Ugh in powershell you have to backslash the double quotes.

Answer (score 14):

Or the `tr` command:

```
echo This++++this+++is+not++done | tr -s '+' ' '
```

Comment: `-s` is very handy. I'd say this is the better solution for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks!  I find that `tr` is a very under-appreciated command.

Comment: Also faster than awk and less to type.

Comment: This answer applies to Awk one-line commands, not inside Awk scripts.

Answer (score 14):

The idiomatic awk solution would be just to translate the input field separator to the output separator:

```
$ echo This++++this+++is+not++done | awk -F'++' '{$1=$1}1'
This this is not done
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this

`echo "This++++this+++is+not++done" | sed -re 's/(\+)+/ /g'`

Answer (score 5):

You could use `sed` too.

```
echo This++++this+++is+not++done | sed -e 's/+\{1,\}/ /g'
```

This matches one or more `+` and replaces it with a space.

Answer (score 3):

For this case I recommend `sed`, this is powerful for substitution and has a short syntax.

Solution `sed`:

```
echo This++++this+++is+not++done | sed -En 's/\\++/ /gp'
```

Result:

```
This this is not done
```

For `awk`:
You must use the `gsub` function for global line substitution (more than one substitution).
The syntax:
`gsub(regexp, replacement [, target])`.
If the third  parameter is ommited then `$0` is the target.
Target must a variable or array element. gsub works in target, overwritten target with the replacement.

Solution awk:

```
echo This++++this+++is+not++done | awk 'gsub(/\\++/," ")
```

Result:

```
This this is not done
```

Comment: Your sed example fails because the backslash is not removed within single quotes. The example would work if you had used double quotes (or removed one of the backslashes). The awk example fails because there is no trailing quote mark. I did not test whether it would fail due to the double backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "This++++this+++is+not++done" | sed 's/++*/ /g'
```

Comment: This answers the task set out in the first line of the question.

Answer (score -7):

If you have access to node on your computer you can do it by installing rexreplace

```
npm install -g regreplace
```

and then run

```
rexreplace '\++' ' ' myfile.txt
```

Of if you have more files in a dir `data` you can do

```
rexreplace '\++' ' ' data/*.txt
```

Comment: If you compare the size of npm to awk and how fast tr can replace compared with rexreplace then you might understand that this is using a bomb to open  a nut.

Comment: It makes no sense to compare npm to awk. I assume you mean the size of rexreplace. The speed is for sure better with tr. The answer seeks to offer the convenience of using a tool where the syntax is more easy to grasp. It reminds me of the discussions when C was introduced, and people argued that the generated code was messy and slow compared to making it in assembly.

Comment: @mathiasrw Often it's not about size or speed.  It's usually about dependencies and maintaining a small footprint that will reliably work everywhere. awk is a rather small system utility already installed on just about every distro you'll encounter.  node/npm are not yet there.