# Why replace operator matches empty string in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

In Powershell (5.1 or 7), I run:

```
PS R:\> "abcdef" -replace '.*','x'
xx
PS R:\> "abcdef" -replace '.+','x'
x
PS R:\> "abcdef" -replace '^.*','x'
x
PS R:\> "abcdef" -replace '^.+','x'
x
PS R:\>
PS R:\> "abcdef" -replace '^','x'
xabcdef
PS R:\>
```

As you can see, in the first run I got `xx` but was expecting a single `x`.
Tried with sed in bash (executables from gitdir/usr/bin; msys I think), and got what I expected.

```
2021-05-01 01:34:27 /r :
$ echo "abcdef" | sed -E s/.*/x/g
x

2021-05-01 01:35:03 /r :
$ echo "abcdef" | sed -E s/.+/x/g
x

2021-05-01 01:35:08 /r :
$ echo "abcdef" | sed -E s/^.*/x/g
x

2021-05-01 01:35:17 /r :
$ echo "abcdef" | sed -E s/^.+/x/g
x

2021-05-01 01:35:20 /r :
$ echo "abcdef" | sed -E s/^/x/g
xabcdef

2021-05-01 01:35:25 /r :
$
```

I have tried the documentation and cant figure out how to understand what is happening.

Comment: Seems this is a regex behavior, not powershell specifically.  2 matches are returned. 
 I cannot explain it though.  https://regex101.com/r/TE7TcT/1

Comment: Perhaps because the very first match is the _zero match_ and the rest is the _or more_ match. (in regex the asteriks means _zero or more matches_) ?

Comment: @Theo Nope, it's the other way around - first match is `abcdef`, second is the empty string between `f` and the end of the string

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen God to know!. I came up with that by anchoring to the end `"abcdef" -replace '.*$','x'` --> `xx`, while anchoring to the beginning of the string `"abcdef" -replace '^.*','x'` returned the single `x`

Comment: This is what RegexBuddy makes of it https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZE5p.png - the same warning is shown when selecting `.NET` so looks like a general `.NET` thing

Comment: Good question; I hope the linked duplicate sheds some more light on the _why_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's find out!

The easiest way to find out *what exactly* was matched by a regex pattern in any version of PowerShell is by using `Regex.Matches()`:

```
PS ~> [regex]::Matches('abcdef', '.*')
    
Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 6
Value    : abcdef

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 6
Length   : 0
Value    :
```

Aha! It's matching the substring `abcdef`, and then the empty string between `f` and the end of the string.

---

In PowerShell 7 we can also use a scriptblock with the replace operator to confirm:

```
PS ~> "abcdef" -replace '.*',{"['$($_.Value)' (length $($_.Length)) starting at $($_.Index)]"}
['abcdef' (length 6) starting at 0]['' (length 0) starting at 6]
```

I'm afraid I don't now *why* the regex engine implementors decided that this behavior was preferable to the behavior of `sed`, but at least we know *what* happens now.

Comment: Nice demonstration; as for the _why_: long discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52369618/45375), but it still doesn't fully make sense to me.

Comment: @mklement0 There's a comment there about "posix leftmost longest match" for sed and awk.  Regex101.com shows 2 matches.

Comment: @mklement0 interesting observations. Having not really given it much thought previously my initial instinct was actually "sed is being weird and 'friendly', .NET is acting how I would expect", along the same lines you point out halfway through (ie. "position N is a perfectly valid offset for macthing")

Answer (score 3):

Select-string showing 2 matches:

```
# select-string highlights matches in ps 7, but you can't see the 2nd match anyway
'abcdef' | select-string .* -AllMatches | % matches   # 2 matches
```

Looks like a .Net thing, even in Powershell 7.  [regex101.com/r/VzxbOT/1](https://regex101.com/r/VzxbOT/1) gives 2 matches as well, so maybe it's sed that's wrong ("posix [leftmost longest match](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/leftmost_longest_rule.html)?"  Should .net follow that standard?), since the /g means global or all matches?

```
[regex]::Replace('abcdef','.*','x')

xx
```

Replace only one time ([Replacing only the first occurrence of a word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089631/replacing-only-the-first-occurrence-of-a-word-in-a-string/40090040#40090040)):

```
$pattern = [regex]'.*'
$pattern.replace('abcdef','x',1)

x
```

[Search and replace in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432209/substitute-a-regex-pattern-using-awk/14432241#14432241) in osx works the same as sed.  Only works in bash for some reason.  Oh you'd have to backslash the required doublequotes in powershell.

```
echo 'abcdef' | awk '{ gsub(/.*/,\"x\"); print }'

x
```

Comment: Yes, `sed` and `awk` (both the BSD/macOS and the GNU/Linux implementations globally match `.*` only _once_; ditto for `mawk`. Python 2.x and Python _up to v3.6_ match only once also, but from what I can tell the majority of engines match _twice_.

Comment: An aside re the unfortunate need to `\ `-escape the `"` chars. PowerShell Core 7.2.0-preview.5 introduced experimental feature `PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing`, which makes this no longer necessary; it works robustly on Unix platforms, but on Windows important accommodations are missing; plus, there are currently bugs - see [GitHub issue #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143).

Comment: Nice, thanks for the regex101 link with explanations.